# Applying a matrix in Three.js does not what I expect

Tags: matrix, three.js, rotation

For a project I am working on I am trying to get get a 3D-model of a building visible in a browser. Of all the elements of the building I have vertices, indices and a matrix3d. This information comes from an application that uses OpenGL to show the elements in a offline program.

Now I am trying to add these elements to my Three.js scene.

I am at the point that I can add elements to the scene defined by the vertices and indices an I can see them by using materials and lights, but I can not rotate and translate them into the right place. For example I add an element like this:

```
var m242242255255 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0xf2f2ff, transparent:true, opacity:1, side:THREE.DoubleSide});
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([821,-15,2825.1,-821,-15,2825.1,-821,-39,2825.1,821,-39,2825.1,-821,-39,54,-821,-15,54,821,-15,54,821,-39,54,-875,-54,0,-821,-54,54,-821,-54,2825.1,821,-54,54,-875,-54,2879.1,821,-54,2825.1,875,-54,0,875,-54,2879.1,875,0,0,821,0,54,821,0,2825.1,-821,0,54,875,0,2879.1,-821,0,2825.1,-875,0,0,-875,0,2879.1]), 3));
geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint16Array([8,9,10,9,8,11,12,10,13,10,12,8,11,14,13,14,11,8,13,15,12,15,13,14,16,17,18,17,16,19,20,18,21,18,20,16,19,22,21,22,19,16,21,23,20,23,21,22,8,22,16,16,14,8,14,16,20,20,15,14,15,20,23,23,12,15,12,23,22,22,8,12,13,18,17,17,11,13,11,17,19,19,9,11,9,19,21,21,10,9,10,21,18,18,13,10]), 1));

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, m242242255255);
mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
mesh.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().set(0,0,-1,0,  -0.42262,-0.90631,0,0,  -0.90631,0.42262,0,0,  64754.68,15569.13,-4647.5,1));
mesh.updateMatrix();
scene.add(mesh);
```

The element shows up in my scene and it looks like is rotated but it is not translated to its correct position.

I can add the translation before the adding of the mesh to the scene, but it feels like it should not be necessary.

```
mesh.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(-64754.68, -15569.13, -4647.5));
mesh.updateMatrix();
```

It also looks like the element is rotated along the wrong axis. It is rotated along the x-axis instead of the z-axis. Can someone tell me what it is I am doing wrong? Should I changed the matrix first to be able to use it in Three.js?

**Edit:**

I just found out that I had to invert my matrix to correct the rotation-problem. So I now have:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([821,-15,2825.1,-821,-15,2825.1,-821,-39,2825.1,821,-39,2825.1,-821,-39,54,-821,-15,54,821,-15,54,821,-39,54,-875,-54,0,-821,-54,54,-821,-54,2825.1,821,-54,54,-875,-54,2879.1,821,-54,2825.1,875,-54,0,875,-54,2879.1,875,0,0,821,0,54,821,0,2825.1,-821,0,54,875,0,2879.1,-821,0,2825.1,-875,0,0,-875,0,2879.1]), 3));
geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint16Array([8,9,10,9,8,11,12,10,13,10,12,8,11,14,13,14,11,8,13,15,12,15,13,14,16,17,18,17,16,19,20,18,21,18,20,16,19,22,21,22,19,16,21,23,20,23,21,22,8,22,16,16,14,8,14,16,20,20,15,14,15,20,23,23,12,15,12,23,22,22,8,12,13,18,17,17,11,13,11,17,19,19,9,11,9,19,21,21,10,9,10,21,18,18,13,10]), 1));

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, m242242255255);
mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
matrix.set(0,0,-1,0,-0.42262,-0.90631,0,0,-0.90631,0.42262,0,0,64754.68,15569.13,-4647.5,1);
matrix.getInverse(matrix);
mesh.applyMatrix( matrix );
mesh.updateMatrix();
mesh.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 64754.68, 15569.13, -4647.5 ) );
mesh.updateMatrix();
scene.add(mesh);
```

But I still have a problem with translating using the matrix. How can I avoid updating the mesh twice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your matrix elements by rows, like so:

```
matrix.set( n11, n12, n13, n14,
            n21, n22, n23, n24,
            n31, n32, n33, n34,
            n41, n42, n43, n44 );
```

It is done this way so it is human-readable.

three.js r.76

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not work. All elements stay positioned at coordinates 0,0,0 and are not translated to their right place.

Answer (score 0):

suppost you ratate in the x, y, z sequence.

```
    rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(rV.y), new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(rV.x));
    rotationMatrix.premultiply(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(rV.z));
    matrix.copy(rM).setPosition(vector3);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Matrix-transformations) for modifying the object's matrix directly

> Note that matrixAutoUpdate must be set to false in this case, and you should make sure *not* to call updateMatrix. Calling updateMatrix will clobber the manual changes made to the matrix, recalculating the matrix from position, scale, and so on.

You'll find that after you call `mesh.updateMatrix()`, the mesh transformation matrix will be different than the one you set. You verify this by comparing `matrix.elements` to `mesh.matrixWorld.elements`, which will be the same after you remove `updateMatrix`.